# Redirect to splash page before home for new visitors

Tags: joomla-3.4

I need to redirect new visitor to a splash page created with joomla article.

I used this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect() {
        var thecookie = readCookie('doRedirect');
        if (!thecookie) {
            window.location = 'prehome';
        }
    }

    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        } else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        redirect();
        createCookie('doRedirect', 'true', '999');
    }
</script>
```

I copied this script in `theme.php` of the template.
It also works if I add the script in a module and publish it.

But for some seconds the homepage is shown before redirecting to the splash page.

Is there a script to prevent the showing the homepage before splash page?

And, is there a script to apply to my `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your redirect script is fired on `window.onload`, and as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520780/when-is-window-onload-fired), that's after all your content is loaded. That's why you see the home page for a moment before a user is redirected.

Try modifying your script like this, and place it between your `<head>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        } else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
    var thecookie = readCookie('doRedirect');
    if (!thecookie) {
        createCookie('doRedirect', 'true', '999');
        window.location = 'prehome';
    }
</script>
```

## Other solutions

You might also consider using a modal popup, some extensions can load the popup once, and set a cookie in order to avoid users to see it again:

1. **NoNumber Modals**
   NoNumber has a nice popup extension called [Modals](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modals), and it has an option to display popup only once (I think you need the pro version for this):

   ```
   {modal html=This modal will only show once|openOnce=1}{/modal}
   ```

   Check out the [demo here](http://demo.nonumber.nl/index.php/12-modals).
2. **Joomla Content Editor**
   The Joomla Content Editor also has a function to display a popup only once. Read more here: https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/tutorials/jcemediabox/item/create-a-media-popup

   ```
    <a href="/instructions.html" class="jcepopup autopopup-single" type="text/html" id="autopopup"></a>
   ```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works better than my script. Thanks very much

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad it works. Happy new year :)

Comment: Happy New Year to you too.